# Redirecting STDOUT to a console inside an async application using Flet

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, stdout, flet

I’m currently working on a project that involves the development of an async app using flet. I would like to implement a console feature, redirecting stdout and stderr to a ft.Text component. I would also like to update the page using the update_async method.
The problem is that I can’t (and I don’t know, I’m always ready to learn) a way to redirect sys.stdout to an async function capable of awaiting page.update_async.

I tried calling an async function inside a sync function, but nothing worked.